# Can you deserialize bytes with memcpy?

Tags: c++, memcpy

If I have a class that has primitives in it, a bunch of ints or chars for example, is it possible to do deserialize and serialize it with memcpy?

```
MyClass toSerialize;
unsigned char byteDump[sizeof(toSerialize)];
memcpy(&byteDump, &toSerialize, sizeof(toSerialize));
WriteToFile(byteDump);
```

Then on another program or computer, do this:

```
MyClass toDeserialize;
unsigned char byteDump[sizeof(toSerialize)];
LoadFile(byteDump);
memcpy(&toDeserialize, &byteDump, sizeof(byteDump));
```

I have cases where this does in fact work in the same program. But if I try to run it on other programs or PCs, it sometimes does not work and `MyClass` will have different values. Is this safe to do or not?

Comment: At least, endianness issue.

Comment: Unless `MyClass` is a [POD type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType) then no you can't use `memcpy` for deserialization *or* the serialization in the first place. And even if it *is* a POD type you could have problems with e.g. endianness issues and possible other incompatibilities between platforms and compilers.

Comment: Also, potentially different class layout regarding padding.

Comment: Also note that pointers can't be serialized as-is. Not even between different processes of the same program (on a modern protected virtual memory OS).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude wouldn't a pointer still qualify as POD?

Comment: @DrewDormann Unfortunately it does. But doing a byte-wise copy of a pointer (which is what `memcpy` does) just copies the pointer and not what it points to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this safe to do or not?

Between different programs or platforms, `memcpy` is **not safe**.  You are not assured that the byte layout of a type will be consistent.

Within the same program on the same platform, a well-formed* type `T` may be serialized with `memcpy` **only if** `is_trivially_copyable_v<T>` is `true`.

`std::atomic` is a type that takes advantage of certain types being bytewise copyable.

---

*A type `T` is considered "well formed" if there are not bugs in the defined or defaulted constructors, assignment operators, or destructor.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.  `memcpy()` was not designed for this.  Having said that, you can get away with it if you don't care about cross-platform issues, for both data and executable.

As long as data is stored and retrieved consistently, `memcpy()` won't care.